# C# - errors downloading Excel 2010

Tags: c#, excel

I have converted an Excel 2003 spread sheet which used the SOAP toolbox (no longer supported) to do some calls to a Web Service, to Excel 2010 using VSTO.

The spread sheet works great and does what its supposed to (mostly), and now I want to make it available to the user from the website.

I would have thought it should be the same as offering the 2003 version, which is still available, so I basically replicated the download button for the Excel 2003 spread sheet which works as it should.

When I try this for the 2010 spread sheet I get an Excel error stating

"Excel found unreadable content in "SpreadSheet_name.xlsx". Do you want to recover the content  of this workbook ? If you trust the source of this workbook, click YES."

Excel then fixes the problem and the spreadsheet can be used as normal.

When I open the spread sheet from the source folder where the download is done from, it opens with no error at all, as it does once the above error has been fixed and the file saved.

This is the code used for the current Excel 2003 download button -

```
Response.WriteFileAsAttachment("application/ms-excel", Server.MapPath("~/pathname/Spreadsheet_2003.xls"), 8192);
Response.End();
```

This is what I have for the 2010 download button click which is the above with the updated MIME info for Excel 2010 -

```
Response.WriteFileAsAttachment("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", Server.MapPath("~/pathname/Spreadsheet_2010.xls"), 8192);
Response.End();
```

I have tried several things that were suggested on various forums and all have the same results.

I am using C# and ASP.Net running thru VS 2010 to test this, so it was suggested that the limited IIS in VS might be a problem ?

Any help or advice would be most appreciated.

Thanks, George.

Comment: I noticed that your extension in the 2010 download button has an "xmls" extension, but your error message has an "xlsx" extension.  I don't think that this is the source of your issue, but it does cause Excel to issue a warning dialog when attempting to open a file in a format that doesn't match the extension.

Comment: Sorry, "xmls" should've been "xls".  Didn't notice in time to fix.

Comment: Sorry, thats just a typo in the text above, in the code the 2nd one is .xlsx

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the remote access comms that we use which causes this problem with downloads. Its not something the company will fix so we have to live with it and work around it. :(